# Livewire или Vue для социальной сети на Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, livewire

Что лучше подойдёт для соцсети с количеством пользователей до 100 000, Livewire или Vue?
С одной стороны на Livewire проще, но каждый запрос работает через сервер(по сути, только в этом проблема), например валидация полей. У Vue всё на клиенте, но это время на рендеринг, нужно компилировать, чтоб хорошо сделать, нужно нужно много чего учесть.

Что ещё нужно учесть при выборе? Может у кого-то уже есть опыт выбора или ухода от технологии в пользу другой?

Comment: какой-то странный вопрос у вас. У вас не может не быть сервера. Он всегда есть, на фронте нельзя хранить данные (localstorage тут не подойдет). Обновив страницу вы всё потеряете. Плюс В браузере всегда можно отключить ту или иную функцию. или валидацию, потому что она на клиенте. Вся валидация итоговая идёт на сервере! Валидация на клиенте идёт для "защиты от дурачка" как правило.  Итог: все запросы работают через сервер. Livewire будет работать так же как и vue только компоненты будете писать на php а не на js. Если будет много анимаций я бы рекомендовал vue, так как js правильное решение

Comment: При Livewire валидация на фронте работает через сервер, отправляя туда запросы. Я про это.

Answer (score 1):

В целом можно сказать что выбор фреймворка в подавляющем количестве случаев - это вкусовщина и выбирается он в основном отталкиваясь от того, насколько просто команде будет работать с проектом. В данной же ситуации сравнение несколько неверное, ибо `Livewire` - full-stack framework, когда `Vue` - фронтовое решение.

Отвечая на вопрос: Я бы предложил вам использовать `Vue` с SSR. Ибо тянуть клиентскую логику на сервер - не хорошо. К тому же у `Vue` существует огромное количество либ и плагинов, если они понадобятся. Кроме того `Vue` сейчас хайпит и в случае возникновения вопросов - на них будет легко найти ответ как в интернетах, так и в чатах.

P.S. - Вообще я бы вам предложил ознакомиться также и с другими вариантами, такими как `React`, `Svelte` etc. Возможно их вам будет достаточно.